# how does "==" operator work in an expression?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a = 10, b = 5, c = 5;
   int d;
   d = b + c == a;
   printf("%d", d);
}
```

In the above code,could any one please explain to me how `d = b + c == a` works?

Comment: Yes, any seasoned C programmer could explain it. However, no one wants to google "C operators" for you. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: This is a platform where i can clear my doubts. So such comments wont help!

Comment: [You have to make some research effort.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) We are not a "gimme teh codez" site.

Comment: Ya agree with you. But if you are not interested please dont answer my question. There are many who can help me.

Answer (score 6):

Because of operator precedence, it is parsed as

```
d = ((b + c) == a);
```

`b + c` is 10, which is equal to `a`, so `d` receives the value of 1, which is how C represents true comparisons.

Comment: -1 you posted 2 seconds after VoidPointer, don't plagiarize. `</irony>`

Answer (score 4):

Based on precedence of operators, binary `+` has higher precedence than `==`. So the statement will be grouped as,

```
d = ( b + c ) == a;
```

Which becomes,

```
d = ( ( b + c ) == a );    // ==>  d = ( 10 == 10 );
```

So, `d` holds the truth value based on the comparison `(b+c) == a` which is `1` because in C comparison operators will return `1` for true and `0` for false.

Answer (score 2):

Its works like this

```
d = (b+c) == a --> (5+5) == 10 ---> 1
```

Which returns 1

Answer (score 2):

`+` operator has higher precedence than `==`.So `d=b+c==a;` parsed as `d=((b+c)==a);`. `b+c` is 10.
so `(10==a)` evaluates true .So `d=1;`